# Background color doesn't fill in the table cell when transformed

Tags: css

When I transform the table, the background color doesn't fill in the table cell completely. How can I solve this problem, please? thanks.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5xw6n93/ This simple table is only to show the problem i am having here.

```css
#style {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-top: 140px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

#style td {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="style">
  <tr>
    <td class="yellow">a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td class="yellow">f</td>
    <td>g</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly discourage you from doing that rotations. Instead, remove them and make 1 row for (obviously) each row.

```html
<table id="style">
  <tr>
    <td class="yellow">a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Edit: another solution, if you really want/need to do that, is to put the content of the cell inside another tag, for example **span**. If you rotate the span, the background of the cell will be ok. You'll have to assign a display: block; to the spans too, if you chose that tag (or any non-block tag).

```html
<!-- Rotate the spans, not the tds -->
<table id="style">
  <tr>
    <td class="yellow"><span>a</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>a</span></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Juan.

Answer (score 1):

You have rotated your td elements inside of your table, rather than you table itself, which is what I'm assuming you were trying to do.

Replace your CSS code, with the following:

```
#style {
    border: 2px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-top: 140px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
} 

#style td {
    padding: 3px; 
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height:22px;
    width: 22px;  
  /* transform: rotate(90deg); */



}

.yellow  {
 background-color:yellow;

}
```

Rotating elements rather than styling them appropriately can become messy, so proceed with caution.

** EDIT **
As per the question from the poster of the question, where the text is to be rotated along with the tds.

**HTML**

```
<table id="style">
<tr><td>g</td></tr>
<tr><td class="yellow">f</td></tr>
<tr><td>e</td></tr>
<tr><td>d</td></tr>
<tr><td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td>
<tr><td class="yellow">a</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#style {
    border: 2px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-top: 140px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
} 

#style td {
    padding: 3px; 
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height:22px;
    width: 22px;  
  transform: rotate(-180deg);  


}

.yellow  {
 background-color:yellow;

}
```

Comment: How can I rotate the letters in the cells in your suggestion? when I tried to rotate the letters with transform in td, the color doesn't fit in the cell.

Comment: @Max I've updated my answer to provide a solution to your follow up question.